# OwnCloud stored file as WEB start page

Tags: linux, email, owncloud, html5

I collect video clips from security cameras in OC. Every 10 min scrip tlook to for new video files and if so, email is send to user who owns particular cameras set. Such mail contain links (one or more) to new video clips like this:

```
https://<my_site>/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Filmy/Kamery/1.mp4
```

All links to films are opened properly in Firefox and Chrome but not in Android based devices But I want to use link to static WEB page with content like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
<video width="400" controls>
<source src="https://<my_site>/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Filmy/Kamery/1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body> 
</html>
```

So I created for each email static WEB page like above and send email with content:

```
https://<my_site>/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/Filmy/Kamery/index_<date_time>.html [/code]
```

But when I click on such link, only content of index_.html is display instead HTML content. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: ownCloud sends special content-type headers to prevent webdav content (e.g. html) from being rendered as far as I know for security reasons. I think I saw some comment on this somewhere but can't find it at the moment